# Defragmentation Error, The Volume (C:) was not Optimized

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, event-viewer

***Event ID 257***

> The volume (C:) was not optimized because an error was encountered:
>   The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)

I have Windows 8.1 *64 Bit* (HDD) and lately I noticed the above event in my Event Viewer. I get every day 3 or 4 of these errors. Anyone found a solution to this ?

---

- SFC /SCANNNOW didn't solve the problem: Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

---

### Solutions that I did not try but might work

1. > Basic steps to use diskpart to assign a drive letter to the system
   >   partition
   >
   > 1. Open an elevated command prompt.
   > 2. Type diskpart and press Enter. You leave the standard command prompt and enter the diskpart utility. (Nothing exciting happens,
   >      don't worry.)
   > 3. Type list disk and press Enter to get a listing of the disks on the system. (More accurately, the disks visible to diskpart.) Figure
   >      out
   >      which disk contains the partition you want to assign a drive letter
   >      to.
   > 4. Type select disk X, where X is the applicable disk number.
   > 5. Type list partition and press Enter to get a listing of recognized partitions on disk X (from step 4). Your desired
   >      partition will the
   >      listed there. If not, go outside and enjoy nature.
   > 6. Type select partition Y, where Y is the applicable partition number.
   > 7. Type assign letter=Z, where Z is the drive letter you wish to assign. Diskpart should reply: DiskPart successfully assigned the
   >      drive letter or mount point.
   >
   > Once the system recognizes the drive letter (a reboot may help; as I
   >   mentioned, I did not reboot before the trim worked, but did have to
   >   wait awhile), you should be able to defrag/trim.
   >
   > To unassign the drive letter:
   >
   > A. Carry out steps 1 - 6 above.
   >
   > B. Type remove and press Enter. Diskpart should reply: DiskPart
   >   successfully removed the drive letter or mount point.
   >
   > I hope this helps.

2. > I am not entirely sure why it helped, but after I had the same
   >   issue (0x80070057 during defrag, chkdsk reports no errors) reseting
   >   the journal seemed to fix it.
   >
   > Open an Administrator command prompt and make use of fsutil:
   >
   > fsutil usn deletejournal /D volume pathname 
   >   fsutil usn createjournal  m=max-value a=alloc-delta volume pathname
   >
   > Eg :
   >   fsutil usn deletejournal /D C: 
   >   fsutil usn createjournal m=1000 a=100 C:
   >
   > Maybe it helps someone else as well.

The answers are from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/optimize-drives-the-parameter-is-incorrect/4d4360e7-37a8-4811-aefd-3d1e8a23b261?page=4)

Comment: As far as I remember Windows disk defragmentation tool requires at least 15% of free disk space to run. Do you have that much free space on C:?

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of free space.

Comment: If you find a solution, please post it. I'm having the same problem and some people have reported the problem is related to optimizing drives that don't have a drive letter assigned.

Comment: @CoryR you can favorite the question and +1 so that you can always come back to see for solutions. I have also searched the web and no one has a clue why this error is reported.

Comment: @CoryR there is now a official solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that Microsoft released a [Hotfix for this issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2929874).

#### Symptoms

When you run the Disk Defragmenter (Defrag.exe) utility on a volume on a computer that's running Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2, the defrag operation fails. Additionally, **event ID 257** is logged in the Application log. This event displays a "The parameter is incorrect" error message. In this case, you may be unable to optimize the volume for space efficiency.

#### Prerequisites

To apply this hotfix, you must be running one of the following operating systems:

- Windows 8.1
- Windows Server 2012 R2

from *KB Article Number: 2929874*

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope this solves also my problem.

Comment: When I tried to install the patch, I was told that the patch is not applicable even though my computer has Windows 8.1 x64 installed.

Comment: The hotfix link is now:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2929874.

Comment: Same here, says this update is not applicable to your computer, even though I'm trying to install it on a Windows 8.1 x64 machine.

Answer (score 1):

It often results from an 'unusual' (such as ^  & or  $ ) character in a file or folder names. Therefore, suggest you use the System File Checker

> sfc /scannow

Which will take some time to complete.

Comment: It did not help. I got this message: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Not sure how things were in 2014, but here in 2017, `/s` is not an option to `sfc` on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: The user had Windows 8.1 and the solution offered is valid. Windows Server 2012 R2.seems specific to corporate IT support and networks and as per http://superuser.com/help/on-topic Server would be off topic.